# Spring caching does not work (SimpleCacheManager)

Tags: spring, caching, javafx

Configuration:

```
@Configuration
@EnableCaching
@ComponentScan("by.bsu.chemistry")
public class AppConfig {

    @Bean
    public CacheManager cacheManager() {
        SimpleCacheManager manager = new SimpleCacheManager();
        manager.setCaches(Collections.singleton(new ConcurrentMapCache("panes")));
        return manager;
    }
}
```

Initialization of spring context:

```
public class Main extends Application {

    public static BorderPane borderPane;

    ConfigurableApplicationContext context;

    @Override
    public void init() throws Exception {
        super.init();
        context = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(AppConfig.class);
    }
```

And usage of cache is in BoxUtils class:

```
@Component
public class BoxUtils {

//some code

@Cacheable(value = {"panes"})
    public Pane getDefaultPane(String title){

        VBox vBox = new VBox();

        //some code

        System.out.println("getDefaultPane(" + title + ")  =   " + vBox);

        return vBox;
    }
```

Every time when method `getDefaultPane(String title)` is invoked, program output in console "`getDefaultPane(......)  =   VBox@........`", thus method worked every time instead of caching results. 
What am I doing wrong?

*In stacktrace before executing `getDefaultPane` cache proxy is not invoked!

** After setting TRACE-level of logging (org.springframework.cache)

```
DEBUG AnnotationCacheOperationSource [AbstractFallbackCacheOperationSource.java:101] Adding cacheable method 'getDefaultPane' with attribute: [Builder[public javafx.scene.layout.Pane by.bsu.chemistry.util.BoxUtils.getDefaultPane(java.lang.String)] caches=[panes] | key='' | keyGenerator='' | cacheManager='' | cacheResolver='' | condition='' | unless='' | sync='false']
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Check `@Cacheable` is `org.springframework.cache.annotation.Cacheable`
2. Set breakpoint into `getDefaultPane` and see in stacktrace if cache proxy invoked
3. Set logging `org.springframework.cache` to TRACE level

Answer (score 0):

Check where you call `getDefaultPane` is called. If it is called in the same class `BoxUtils` then it will not work.Only external method calls coming in through the proxy are intercepted.